# Evernote Android Job

Tags: android, evernote

I am using Evernote Android Job for scheduling my sync job to be run in every 15 minutes(9000_000 MS). I have successfully done that but what i need is , don't run the job immediately. Currently it immediately run and then in every time interval.

```
public static void scheduleJob(Long intervalMS) {
    new JobRequest.Builder(JobSync.TAG)
            .setPeriodic(intervalMS)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .setUpdateCurrent(false)
            .build()
            .schedule();
}
```

> How can i skip immediate run of job ? i did research on this but unable to find exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Timer` and call your `scheduleJob` when the time has elapsed, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
private Timer mTimer;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask(){ 
            @Override public void run(){
                scheduleJob(Some_Long); 
             } 
         }, 0, 1000); 
    }

    public static void scheduleJob(Long intervalMS) { 
        new JobRequest.Builder(JobSync.TAG) 
                .setPeriodic(intervalMS) 
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.CONNECTED) 
                .setUpdateCurrent(false) 
                .build() 
                .schedule(); 
    }

}
```